# Calculate $\iint_D\frac{a\sqrt{2az-z^2}}{z}\text{d}y\text{d}z$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to integrate this:
$$
\iint_D\frac{a\sqrt{2az-z^2}}{z}\text{d}y\text{d}z
$$
on
$$
D=\begin{cases}
2z^2-2az=y^2\\
a\le z\le 2a
\end{cases}
$$
But after trying some substitution, I can't find a resonable way to integrate it. I know it's silly, but I don't know how to get further ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a bit of nitpicking.  You really should write
$$
\iint_D\frac{a\sqrt{2az-z^2}}{z}\;dA
$$
which becomes
$$
\int_a^{2a}\int_{-\sqrt{2z^2-2az}}^{\sqrt{2z^2-2az}}\frac{a\sqrt{2az-z^2}}{z}\;dy\;dz
=\int_a^{2a}\frac{a\sqrt{2az-z^2}}{z}\cdot 2\sqrt{2z^2-2az}\;dz
$$
$$
=\text{sgn}(a)2a\sqrt{2}\int_a^{2a}\sqrt{-z^2+3az-2a^2}\;dz
$$
Complete the square to get
$$
\text{sgn}(a)2a\sqrt{2}\int_a^{2a}\sqrt{(a/2)^2-(z-3a/2)^2}\;dz
$$
Use $u=z-3a/2$ to get
$$
\text{sgn}(a)2a\sqrt{2}\int_{-a/2}^{a/2}\sqrt{(a/2)^2-u^2}\;du
$$
Now use trig sub (or, better yet, a table of integration identities) to get
$$
\text{sgn}(a)2a\sqrt{2}\left[\frac{u}{2}\sqrt{(a/2)^2-u^2}+\frac{a^2}{8}\text{arcsin}\frac{2u}{a}\right]_{-a/2}^{a/2}
=\text{sgn}(a)\frac{a^3\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}
$$

Comment: Good solution, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Limits of $y$: $-\sqrt{2z^2-2az} \to \sqrt{2z^2-2az}$

Limits of $z$: $a \to 2a$

$$I = \int^{2a}_{a}\int^{\sqrt{2z^2-2az}}_{-\sqrt{2z^2-2az}} \frac{a\sqrt{2az-z^2}}{z}dydz = \int^{2a}_a 2a\sqrt{2az-z^2}\sqrt{2z^2-2az}\frac{1}{z}dz$$

Cancelling $z$ from Nr and Dr

$I = \int^{2a}_a2\sqrt2a\sqrt{2a-z}\sqrt{z-a}dz = 2\sqrt2a\int^{2a}_a\sqrt{2a-z}\sqrt{z-a}\ dz$

$I = 2\sqrt2a\int^{2a}_a\sqrt{-z^2+3az-2a^2}dz$

By completing the square

$I = 2\sqrt2a\int^{2a}_a\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{4}-(z-\frac{3a}{2}})^2dz 
 = a\sqrt2\int^{2a}_a\sqrt{{a^2-(2z-3a^2)}}dz$

Let $u=2z-3a\implies dz = \frac{du}{2} $

$I = {a\sqrt2}\frac{1}{2}\int^{a}_{-a}\sqrt{a^2-u^2}du$

$I = 2\frac{a\sqrt2}{2}\bigg[\frac{u}{2}\sqrt{a^2-u^2}+\frac{a^2}{2}\sin^{-1}(\frac{u}{a})\bigg]^{a}_{0}$

$I = a\sqrt2\bigg[0 - 0 +\frac{a^2}{2}\cdot\pi/2\bigg] = a\sqrt{2}a^2\frac{\pi}{ 4} = a^3\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt2}$

Comment: Thanks for replying! I've solved it.

Comment: You're welcome:)